# Rename files in directory that are found in CSV that match a column then insert header row with name and date

Tags: python, shell, csv, awk, sed

Trying to solve a problem I asked earlier that couldn't be done with postgres sql query.  So I moved on to trying to find another way to do it.

Essentially - what I have directory lets call it **server** that has multiple CSV files in it with the UUID as the name of the csv.

```
localhost Server]$ tree
.
├── 503336947449727e6f99de97c0a22a98.csv
├── 503340d499169677a0ad8c97f4c75a6d.csv
├── 5033b53f9462e04e4665f7b18993193d.csv
└── 529993499c47a442cab8a6ccba00dee4.csv
```

Inside that CSV looks like the following:

```
2016-03-24 20:04:00,0.405
2016-03-24 20:05:00,0.769
2016-03-24 20:06:00,1.217
2016-03-24 20:07:00,1.355
2016-03-24 20:08:00,0.369
2016-03-24 20:09:00,0.338
2016-03-24 20:10:00,4.443
2016-03-24 20:11:00,1.195
2016-03-24 20:12:00,0.342
2016-03-24 20:13:00,0.351
2016-03-24 20:14:00,0.646
2016-03-24 20:15:00,0.879
```

Now I am trying to do a couple of things.  First take a reference file that has all of the server names and UUID mappings in it.

servers.csv contains the following:

```
server3,50337efc58f19945205d89e9e5a8a3c1
desktop1,503336947449727e6f99de97c0a22a98
serv4,50330e69efa7c4470061855358d11610
server02,52f7df2e6641e211a33f7ff1ffd95514
small-8k,5033b53f9462e04e4665f7b18993193d
small-9k,5033af5b3616a679d20abe9001a7e897
large-64k,5033009b928e1903e3a39ae78a8e2d25
```

Ideally what i need to do is read the servers.csv file into an array then search through the folder and rename files to match the server name.  So an example would be as follows:

```
localhost Server]$ tree
.
├── desktop1.csv
├── 503340d499169677a0ad8c97f4c75a6d.csv
├── small-8k.csv
└── 529993499c47a442cab8a6ccba00dee4.csv
```

Additionally - I need to add the headers to each file as the first row to look like this date,server.

So ideally the newly renamed CSV example desktop1.csv would look like the following:

Inside that CSV looks like the following:

```
date,desktop1
2016-03-24 20:04:00,0.405
2016-03-24 20:05:00,0.769
2016-03-24 20:06:00,1.217
2016-03-24 20:07:00,1.355
2016-03-24 20:08:00,0.369
2016-03-24 20:09:00,0.338
2016-03-24 20:10:00,4.443
2016-03-24 20:11:00,1.195
2016-03-24 20:12:00,0.342
2016-03-24 20:13:00,0.351
2016-03-24 20:14:00,0.646
2016-03-24 20:15:00,0.879
```

I have been struggling with this for a couple days... trying to develop which language would be the easiest to do from shell.  My guess is a combination of awk and sed will get me there, but struggling with both.

I started researching on python which is a possible solution that could make the renaming possible with glob and all the files renamed.  However not versed in python.

I was able to clean up some of the files that were part of the servers.csv file.

```
cut -d, -f1-2 VMInfo.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/\-/,"",$i)} 1' | sed 's/"//g' > servers.csv
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE - @Ed - this is what the output looks like for me.

```
localhost output]$ sh -x testin.sh 
+ mv server server.bk
+ mkdir server
+ awk -F, '
NR==FNR { map[$2]=$1; next }
FNR==1 { close(out); out="server/"map[FILENAME]".csv"; print "date,"map[FILENAME] > out }
{ print > out }
' servers.csv server.bk/503336947449727e6f99de97c0a22a98.csv server.bk/503340d499169677a0ad8c97f4c75a6d.csv server.bk/50335a21c2507fc702864fa9ee7e2563.csv server.bk/50335ab3ab5411f88b77900736338bc6.csv server.bk/50338e29d3414fc4c04baa95772e8454.csv server.bk/5033c14e463120a8dcace7baaee17577.csv server.bk/5033c52713310df05c3ab04f6c4cf293.csv server.bk/5033d82b24982b4a8ac9fd73ec1880f7.csv server.bk/5033d9951846c1841437b437f5a97f0a.csv server.bk/5033db62b38f86605f0baeccae5e6cbc.csv server.bk/5033dc788480a7eab4fd0a586477f856.csv server.bk/5033f3c162b5e0e3bd01db1b3faa542d.csv server.bk/529993499c47a442cab8a6ccba00dee4.csv
```

Update @Ed - Still running into the same thing.

```
 [localhost output]$ sh -x testin.sh 
 + mv server server.bk
 + mkdir server
 + awk -F, '
 NR==FNR { map[$2".csv"]=$1; next }
 FNR==1 { close(out); out="server/"map[FILENAME]".csv"; print "date,"map[FILENAME] > out }
 { print > out }
 ' servers.csv server.bk/503336947449727e6f99de97c0a22a98.csv server.bk/503340d499169677a0ad8c97f4c75a6d.csv server.bk/50335a21c2507fc702864fa9ee7e2563.csv server.bk/50335ab3ab5411f88b77900736338bc6.csv server.bk/50338e29d3414fc4c04baa95772e8454.csv server.bk/5033c14e463120a8dcace7baaee17577.csv server.bk/5033c52713310df05c3ab04f6c4cf293.csv server.bk/5033d82b24982b4a8ac9fd73ec1880f7.csv server.bk/5033d9951846c1841437b437f5a97f0a.csv server.bk/5033db62b38f86605f0baeccae5e6cbc.csv server.bk/5033dc788480a7eab4fd0a586477f856.csv server.bk/5033f3c162b5e0e3bd01db1b3faa542d.csv server.bk/529993499c47a442cab8a6ccba00dee4.csv

 [localhost output]$ cat servers.csv | grep 5033f3c162b5e0e3bd01db1b3faa542d
 vpool02,5033f3c162b5e0e3bd01db1b3faa542d
```

It doesn't seem to be renaming the file to vpool02.csv

Comment: this would certainly be possible, possibly easiest, and definitely the most maintainable in Python (i.e. when you come back in 6 months and need to adjust how the script works, if you're not working with sed/awk on a daily basis you probably wont remember what the incantations mean, to say nothing if you get hit by a bus tomorrow)

Comment: From what i am seeing that seems to be the most viable option.  I am even willing to look at PHP as well this is with a web server.

Comment: @WayneWerner you are confusing sed with awk and there is no tool named `sed/awk` just like there is no tool named `python/grep` - they are 2 completely different tools each with their own syntax and semantics. sed is the one with incantations - awk is an algol-based language like C.

Comment: @EdMorton I think you misunderstood - I was not confusing, nor conflating sed with awk; the OP was asking about a variety of tools and said "a combination of awk and sed". I was using the `and/or` form of `/`, meaning `if you're not working with sed and/or awk on a daily basis`. If the OP had said "a combination of python and grep" then using "python/grep" would also have been perfectly applicable.

Comment: @Wayne fair enough but it's misleading to tar awk with seds brush wrt the syntactic "incantations" (completely valid observation for sed, completely wrong for awk). Jared - you never need sed + awk since when you are using awk you do not need sed. Sed is for simple substiutions on individual lines, that is all - all of it's arcane incantations for doing more than that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: I actually find awk incantations to be more arcane than sed - of course I really only use sed for simple `s/this/that/`, so I couldn't tell you if there's really any more than that (besides that I know it inherits from ed, so I assume quite a few of the ed commands also work on it). Not *terribly* more arcane, but I'm also no longer a beginner in the *nix world, so I at least know what kinds of things I should Google for when I see something like `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/\-/,"",$i)} 1'`

Comment: Once you know C or any other Algol-based language all you have to know to use awk is that a) it has an implicit while-readline loop, b) each script is made of `<condition> { <action> }` statements (default condition true, default action print the current record), and c) it populates/uses about a dozen variables necessary to common text processing applications. You DO have to learn that (you can't guess it from a working knowledge of C) but the only hard part is the paradigm shift to understanding awk does all of the common stuff for you and all that's left for you is writing the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like this (untested):

```
mv server server.bk &&
mkdir server &&
awk -F, '
NR==FNR { map["server.bk/"$2".csv"]=$1; next }
FNR==1 { close(out); out="server/"map[FILENAME]".csv"; print "date,"map[FILENAME] > out }
{ print > out }
' servers.csv server.bk/*.csv
```

At the end of running the above, your original CSV files will be in the directory named "server.bk" which you can remove if you like by adding `&& rm -rf server.bk` at the end so it's only removed if the awk script succeeded.

If you're considering using a shell loop for this, then read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I threw together in Python:

```
import csv
import os
import sys

# This is mostly for convenience. Python convention is that all caps
# are "constants", but there's nothing that enforces that                                                                                                                                                              
FILEPATH = 'servers'
SERVER_FILE = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'servers.csv'

with open(SERVER_FILE) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:

        # This is called unpacking, the csv reader will read
        # row as a list of 2 elements, since that's how many you
        # have in your csv file. If you change your server.csv file
        # format, this line will have to change.                                                                                                                                        
        name, uuid = row
        try:

            # Python needs the `\` line continuation marker to let this
            # go over two lines. Note that there can be *no* spaces after
            # the `\`                                                                                                                        
            with open(os.path.join(FILEPATH, uuid+'.csv')) as infile,\
                    open(os.path.join(FILEPATH, name+'.csv'), 'w') as outfile:

                # Note that I'm not creating a csv reader or writer here,
                # because I'm assuming that there is no comma in the server
                # name. If there is, you'd want to create a writer just to
                # avoid having to manually escape the field.
                outfile.write('date,'+name+'\n')

                # After writing the header we can just write the contents
                # of the csv file
                outfile.write(infile.read())

            # And now we delete the old file that has the wrong name
            os.unlink(infile.name)
        except FileNotFoundError:

            # Technically this exception could also be raised if
            # the path you were writing to did not exist, but
            # since we're writing to the same directory, this should be fine.
            print('Warning, no {}.csv file found'.format(uuid))
```

Comment: Ran into a bit of an error with this...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename.py", line 37, in <module>
    except FileNotFoundError:
NameError: name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined

Reading your last comments on that script saying that it needs to be run all from the same directory.

Comment: the only portion i changed is                                                                                                                                                            
`FILEPATH = 'SAN_Read_Latency' -  `
├── 5033f3c162b5e0e3bd01db1b3faa542d.csv
├── 529993499c47a442cab8a6ccba00dee4.csv
├── rename.py
└── servers.csv

Comment: actually reading through your script a bit more - i need to have it setup like this if i am reading it correctly: 

rootFolder
-rename.py
-servers.csv
--SAN_Read_Latency
---uuid.csv

Because it looks like you are searching the FILEPATH and then looking for uuid+'.csv' as the infile - then renaming it and spitting it out as the new file name.

Comment: I think `FileNotFoundError` may be new in Python 3.

Comment: @Jared I've updated the script to be able to take the `servers.csv` on the command line, so you can do something like `python script.py /path/to/servers.csv`. You could also modify the script to take the `FILEPATH` from the command line as well. If this is the best answer to your question, you can mark the check over on the left hand side `<-----------` that says this is the accepted answer. Or if another answer solves your problem better, accept that one. (You can also upvote answers that you found helpful, even if they're not the one you accepted).

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=,; while read a b; 
   do 
      mv $b $a; 
      sed -i "1i\date,$a" $a; 
   done < servers.csv
```

p.s. caveat emptor, there is mv and inplace edit.  test with a copy first.

Comment: What are you considering the variables a and b are? I have multiple files so this would have to be in another loop correct?  The reason I ask that is because if i have 30 to 100 files in a directory this would loop through a and b.

Comment: it loops through the lines (records) in your servers.csv file and parses based on IFS which is set to comma.  That is, a is set to the first field and b to the second field.  Ideally you use `read -r` for backlash handling but not necessary in your case.  Doesn't matter how many files are it delegates finding the right file to `mv` command.

Comment: another comment on writing a program for this task.  Don't reinvent the wheel (except for learning, that is) for tasks that can be done easily with the unix tool chain.